# Coloring cells in pandas in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to color specific cells in my dataframe based on the cell values, part of the dataframe looks like this -

```
BF     Bin   PW     BC
1      1      3     No
0      1      3     Yes
1      1      3     AC
1      1      3     AC
1      1      3     No
1      1      3     IC
1      1      3     No
```

There are hundreds of rows so the BC column continues to switch between the 4 values, No, Yes, AC, and IC. I need them to be 4 different colors throughout the entire datframe. I've tried making function, using styles, and the report gets generated, but it the output sheet is still color-less. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried the following functions :

```
def highlight_background(val):
    col_dict = {"AC": "grey", "IC" : "orange", "Yes" : "green" , "No" : "red"}
    if val in col_dict:
        return 'Background-color: %s'% col_dict[val]
```

I've also tried something like this

```
def highlight_cell(val):
    if val == 'AC':
        color = 'gray'
    elseif val ==" IC":
        color = 'orange 
    elseif val == 'Yes':
       color == 'green' 
    elseif val == 'No
       color == 'red'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Comment: can you include the code you have written so far? :-)

Comment: Does "output sheet" mean Excel worksheet?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question. Output sheet means Excel Worksheet correct.

Comment: `return 'background-color: {%s}' % col_dict[val]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `jinja2` (pip install jinja2) before run the code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
foutput = r'd:/temp/styled_dataframe.xlsx'
sample = {
    'BF': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Bin': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'PW': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'BC': ['No', 'Yes', 'AC', 'AC', 'No', 'IC', 'No']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)
def color_cells(val):
    color_mapping = {
        'No': 'red',
        'Yes': 'green',
        'AC': 'gray',
        'IC': 'orange'
    }
    return f'background-color: {color_mapping.get(val, "white")}'
format_df = df.style.applymap(color_cells, subset=['BC'])
format_df.to_excel(foutput, engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Styler` Object but it requires `Jinja2`.

If that is okay, you can try the following approach -

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'BF': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Bin': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'PW': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'BC': ['No', 'Yes', 'AC', 'AC', 'No', 'IC', 'No']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def highlight_cells(value):
    color_mapping = {
        'No': 'background-color: red',
        'Yes': 'background-color: green',
        'AC': 'background-color: blue',
        'IC': 'background-color: yellow',
    }
    return color_mapping.get(value, '')

styled_df = df.style.applymap(highlight_cells, subset=['BC'])

styled_df.to_excel('styled_dataframe.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: I tried this but I got an error - "'Styler' object is not subscriptable". Any ideas?